# Aligning characters of different font sizes in CSS

Tags: html, css

What I am trying to achieve is to have two separate lines of text, with different font sizes, for which each character lines up well with a character from the other line.

Current state here

```css
span {
  letter-spacing: 0.12em;
  font-family: monospace, ubuntu_monobold, Courier New, monaco, terminal, courier, system;
  font-size: 1em;
}

.highlight {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 0px;
  word-spacing: normal;
}

.small {
  top: .9em;
  padding-bottom: 1px;
  opacity: 0.6;
  font-size: 70%;
  letter-spacing: .45em;
}
```

```html
<span class="small">gggggggggggggggggggg&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;GGGGGGGGGGGGGGG?GGGGG</span>
<span class="big">GGAAGGCCCCACAGCGTCTTCTGTACTATGAGGGGTCTATTACTGTGCCACCTTCTGACA</span>
```

**[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6gmhgy9x/)**

```
letter-spacing: .45em;
```

Is what I am using to achieve this.

Now the obvious and "easy" solution is to use a table, with a column for each character, however, there can be lots of characters on one line and this would add a lot of elements to the DOM, which I would like to avoid if possible.

So can someone tell me if this is possible using only CSS ?

Thanks

Comment: I guess with tables you'll encounter another problem; table rows don't flow to the next 'line'. The only solution I see that quick is to wrap each character in a span, set them as `display: inline-block`. Calculate the width of the widest, and set this width to each and every span. You'll get the same amount of dom elements though. Plus a little script running

Comment: The text doesn't actually wrap in the app, so tables wouldn't be a problem. Thanks for the advice though :)

Comment: Would something like this be a good solution for you? https://jsfiddle.net/oun1oq0x/1/

Comment: Would you be okay with using monospaced (fixed-width) fonts? I guess that would open up the possibility of doing some math to adjust the character-spacing, without adding DOM elements. Haven't tried yet, though.

Comment: @domsson he is using monospace

Comment: @dsasko Ah, right! And I just saw you already put my idea into practice. Well done! Next question would probably be if it would be possible with CSS only (some pre-defined classes based on font-size?). Anyway, I think you could probably turn this into an answer already.

Comment: As a kind of hack, you can use the same font size in both lines, but wrap each character in the 2nd line in a separate `span` and make these `span`s appear smaller with `transform:scale(...)`.

Comment: I guess IlyaStreltsyn made a good css-only solution. And i just saw that while writing my fiddle Giorgio also suggested the same thing.

Comment: @dsasko Your solution definitely works, and does save a couple DOM elements as compared to tables.

Comment: @IlyaStreltsyn This might be a good compromise. It saves DOM elements as compared to using a table. Thanks